# Asterisk stasis application

Tags: asterisk-ari

I'm a little new on Asterisk ARI (and I love it...), so where ever I look I see the ARI Status application, but I couldn't find the path where the Stasis application should actually be on the server.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Stasis application?  https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+16+Application_Stasis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by 'status application? ARI is event base, so you need to open a websocket that will listen to ARI events and to register your application. The websocket should receive a StasisStart event when the application starts and a StasisEnd event in the end.

For more information you can read in asterisk documentation: 
https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=29395573

I personally use ari4java, if you want to read about it: https://github.com/l3nz/ari4java

hope it helps :)